# Docker: How can I get the complete container id of a existing container?

Tags: docker, containers

Ive been learning about Docker for the last months, I was watching one training tutorial on udemy. I did docker ps -a to check the containers I have (all of them) and for learning purposes I was looking for a command that gives me the full container id of a container.

[image: docker ps -a]

Lets say that from this picture, I want the full container_id of: 8a7815ffd059

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets say that from this picture, I want the full container_id of: 8a7815ffd059

```
docker inspect 8a78 | grep Id
```

Answer (score 6):

Directly with the ps command:

```
docker ps --no-trunc
```

With inspect:

```
docker inspect 8a78 | grep Id
```

Answer (score 1):

This command should give you what you want:

```
docker container inspect --format "{{.Id}}" 8a78
```

and nothing besides the container id (e.g., no cruft to sort through)

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
docker inspect ${the id you get in docker ps}
```

You get a pretty big *json* with all the details about the container. The first key in the object is `Id`, which is what you are looking for